# com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/facebook/AccessToken.class

Tags: cordova, android-studio, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-facebook-plugin, facebook-analytics

I am working on `facebook analytics` in `phonegap` platform. I am already having `facebook plugins` for login and sign up that is working perfectly.

`Facebook plugins` having it's own module. Which is `path: "phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib", configuration: "release"`. You can see this in below `gradle` file.

I have tried some of the SO solutions but not worked for me.

After adding `compile dependencies` for `facebook analytics` i am getting following error.

**Error Log:**

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/facebook/AccessToken.class
```

Here is my `build.gradle`.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    // SUB-PROJECT DEPENDENCIES START
    debugCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: "CordovaLib", configuration: "release")
    debugCompile project(path: "phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib", configuration: "debug")
    releaseCompile project(path: "phonegap-facebook-plugin:FacebookLib", configuration: "release")
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:+"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:+"
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.9.1"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:+"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:+"
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.10@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally i have solved the issue.

The issue is with `Android Studio` version.

The version of my `Android Studio is 2.2.2` when i am trying to execute app with this version it's getting error.

But when i have downgraded `Android Studio` version `2.2.1` then all working fine and executing without error.